# Unable to flash zip made by ZIPme app

Tags: twrp, zip

Device details:

YU Yuphoria

Android 6.0 Marshmallow (AOSP custom firmware)

Root Access: Not yet

Bootloader: Unlocked

Recovery: TWRP v2.8.7.0

I made a flashable zip of my apps along with their data through [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zip.me&hl=en) while I was on CyanogenMod 12.1 (with root access). Now when I try to flash that zip file in the ROM I mentioned above, I'm unable to do so.. I get an error:

```
ZIP file is corrupt
```

I'm unable to make out what's causing this error.. I could assume that the app which I used is not a good option for me to make zips, but many users have tried that app & gained success.. Please help me troubleshoot this..

Comment: The very obvious first question is: Have you tried to unzip manually, e.g. on your computer?

Comment: Of Course yes. The zip contained three folders: one was META-INF, one with the app data which was stored on the SD Card, and the last one was named data, which contained two sub folders, one with the app apk, and the other with the app data which is stored in the device /data partition.. I just can't flash it

Comment: Can you put the updater-script content here ?

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf I've copied the content of the updater-script & uploaded it as a text file: http://www63.zippyshare.com/v/i4ffcGPO/file.html

Comment: ok every thing looks good in the script ,I still think it's a zip file problem so ,did you try unziping then ziping then flashing ? zip the file with 7zip or winrar make sure you zip it as .zip with a low compression level for better compatibility

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf I tried unzipping & zipping again with 7zip.. but still no success.. same error.. "Zip file is corrupt"

Comment: ok I see can you test this dummy zip I made ,it does nothing just flash your first zip that say curupted then flash my zip and then copy the recoveryX.log from your sdcard and show them to me

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf where is the link to that zip you made?

Comment: oops my bad sorry for that here you go https://www.dropbox.com/s/ynsqy5z1gahy6zg/DummyZip.zip?dl=0